# Close TinyMCE editor upon save_onsavecallback callback

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have the following script which works perfectly, except after the content is saved, the editor remains open.  How can I close the TinyMCE editor in the save_onsavecallback callback?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#document",
    inline: true,
    plugins: ["advlist lists print preview anchor paste save"],
    save_enablewhendirty: true,
    save_onsavecallback: function() {
        $.post('index.php?cid=stuff2fix',{task:"save",document:$("#document").html(),CSRF:$('#CSRF').val()});
        //CLOSE EDITOR NOW 
    },
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | save"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know which instance of the mce to remove and then call .remove() on the instance. I have modified the code so it will remove tinemce after clicking save.

The site that helped me was http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9175

`tinymce.init({
            selector: "#document",
            inline: true,
            plugins: ["advlist lists print preview anchor paste save"],
            save_enablewhendirty: true,
            save_onsavecallback: function(inst) {
                $.post('index.php?cid=stuff2fix',{task:"save",document:$("#document").html(),CSRF:$('#CSRF').val()});
                inst.remove();
            },
            toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | save"
        });`